# Is a monster considered "destroyed" if I tribute it?

Tags: yu-gi-oh

Say that I have activated the Trap Card [Shattered Axe](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Shattered_Axe) on my opponent's monster:

> Activate this card by targeting 1 face-up monster on the field. During each of your Standby Phases: It loses 500 ATK. When that target is destroyed, destroy this card.

Before I get a chance to attack it in battle, my opponent manages to tribute the target. Does this mean that the target is "destroyed", and thus Shattered Axe is destroyed along with it? Or is the target not destroyed and Shattered Axe remains on the field, despite the fact that the target is no longer there?

I ask because *Yu-Gi-Oh! Duel Links* (a mobile version of the game) does not destroy Shattered Axe if the target card is tributed. It just sits on the field clogging up space and having the turn counter run indefinitely if the monster is removed by tribute. I don't know if that's a bug or intended behavior.

Comment: `I ask because Yu-Gi-Oh! Duel Links (a mobile version of the game) does not destroy Shattered Axe if the target card is tributed.` the same occurs with `Call of the Haunted` in ygopro. Checking the [Rulings for Call of the Haunted on Yu-Gi-Oh! Wikia](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Card_Rulings:Call_of_the_Haunted) doesn't suggest an answer. My thoughts are that its effects are _temporary_ (when is resolving in a chain), but as an _continuous_ trap card, it stays in the field until is directly destroyed (i.e, MST, Heavy Storm, Dust Tornado, etc).

Comment: As a side comment, it is perhaps not a great idea to take YGOPro or others as "how things should work", as their programmers could have made some omission mistake on the rules.

Comment: @DarkCygnus *Duel Links* is at least an official product from Konami so it *should* be accurate. And even if not, there’s a disclaim in the game saying that if they make a programming error, they are still considered to have the rules correct for the purposes of competitive gameplay and such (you can’t write to them and say you should have won the match due to a rules error).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the official rulebook of *Yu-Gi-Oh!*, "destroy" means

> A card is destroyed when it is sent to the Graveyard due to battle
>   between monsters or by an effect that destroys a card. A card that is
>   returned from the field to the hand or Deck, or, that is sent to the
>   Graveyard as a cost or Tribute, is NOT considered “destroyed.”

This can be found in the [rulebook](http://www.yugioh-card.com/en/rulebook/SDCR_Rulebook_EN.pdf) in the glossary part.

Even though *Duel Links* is a simplified version of the original game, it should follow the basic rules.

Answer (score 3):

No. From a legal standpoint, "destroyed" only refers to a situation where a card is either destroyed by an effect that specifically says "destroy" or by battle. When you tribute a card, it is not considered either, but is rather considered a cost than a destruction.